# Can a Scribe API be configurable in run-time?

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

**Summary**
I am writing an application which uses Scribe to connect to an OAuth Server. I need to be able to change the endpoints in run-time (without recompiling). Is this possible?

**More details**
A java server application is using scribe to connect to an OAuth server. The OAuth-server is developed in-house, so I am extending `DefaultApi10a` to define the endpoints.

There are multiple instances of the OAuth-server, and I need to be able to configure my server application (in run-time) which one to connect to. But it seems that the endpoints are intended to be hardcoded in my sub-class of `DefaultApi10a`. Is there a good way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple way but I know these two ways.

1. Fetch URL from database at run time and hit according to that
2. Put  URL in a config file and add a property file change listener in your java program.

Comment: Yes, I go with option 2 of those. The problem is that the API object (the instance of the subclass to `DefaultApi10a`) is created by a factory method and then kept as a private member, so I can't set any parameters inside the object via a constructor, get-methods or similar.

Comment: Let me understand, you have an getter method inside your API which returns the hard coded endpoint url am I right?

Comment: No issue modify your getter method instead of returning harcoded string just load the properties file with key value and get the value by providing key. Suppose URL is changed no need to modify Ur java code just change property file and when you hit getter method it will load property file and will return new latest URL